Have inline code in section titles?
I'm trying to display an inline code within my section titles.

Right now I'm using \codeword to display inline code within the document
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\codeword}{v}{%
\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
}

If I add \codeword in \section{foobar} i.e., \section{\codeword{foo} bar}, I just get an error

LaTeX cmd: Verbatim-like command '\codeword' illegal in argument.


Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
 }

I also have a section title that is a child of (subheader for?)\subsubsection{} called \paragraph{}. The code for \paragraph{} is added below (I got it off someone from
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

I also want to be able to add an inline code to the \paragraph{} section title.

LaTeX cmd: Verbatim-like command '\codeword' illegal in argument.  tells you the reason, better use a texttt  to emulate the style. I would not recommend to use the color as t will look out of place both in the heading and the toc. Rather just keep your original definition to use it in the text.
